# How to create a zip file in CMIS?

Tags: zip, java-7, cmis, apache-chemistry, cmis-workbench

I'm pretty new in CMIS and I'm having a little trouble on the zip topic. I need to create a zip file in the Document Service and after a loop where I create 12 files, I need to add them into to the zip.

The 12 files are created successfully. I need to create the zip before the loop and move the 12 files to the zip...but I don't know how to solve this.
In other tries I've managed to create the zip (wasn't possible to open it) but I couldn't move the 12 files. Please help.

SOLVED!
I've managed to solve this. I've created a temp zip where I was putting the files that I was creating and after the 12 files inserted in the zip I've uploaded in the CMIS :)

Answer (score 1):

Visit alfresco documentation given in following link, this will help.
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/pra/1/tasks/opencmis-ext-workbench.html